# Load Accordian Panel on click rather than page load

Tags: javascript

I am using a Google Map and Street View javascript code within two panels using Bootstrap Accordian. The first panel contains the map and the second contains the street view. Currently both panels load their JS code on page load but the second panel is collapsed so only the Map panel is visible.

Is it possible to delay the loading of the second panel which contains the street view code until the user clicks to expand/unhide the content rather than loading it all on page load?

Thanks

```
<div class="panel-group" id="accordion">
<div class="panel panel-default">
<div class="panel-heading">
<h4 class="panel-title">
<a class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion"
href="#collapse1">Local Map</a></h4></div>
<div id="collapse1" class="panel-collapse collapse in">
<div class="panel-body">
**Google Map JS**
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="panel panel-default">
<div class="panel-heading">
<h4 class="panel-title">
<a class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" 
href="#collapse2">Street View</a></h4></div>
<div id="collapse2" class="panel-collapse collapse">
<div class="panel-body">
<div id="pano" style="width: 400px; height: 300px;"></div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>

<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&sensor=false"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
$(".accordion-toggle").on('click',function(){
if($(this).attr('href') =="#collapse2"){
alert('');function initialize() {
var point= new google.maps.LatLng(51.524964,-0.34146399999997357);
var panoramaOptions = {
position: point,
pov: {
heading: 12.399999999999999,
pitch: 6.94
}
};
var panorama = new     
google.maps.StreetViewPanorama(document.getElementById('pano'),panoramaOptions);
map.setStreetView(panorama);
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
}
});
});
}
});
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try something like this:

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Example of Twitter Bootstrap 3 Accordion</title>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
<script src="http://getbootstrap.com/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&sensor=false"></script>

<style type="text/css">
    .bs-example{
        margin: 20px;
    }
</style>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$(".accordion-toggle").on('click',function(){
if($(this).attr('href') =="#collapse2"){
    alert('hi');
    initialize();
}
});
});


function initialize() {
      var fenway = new google.maps.LatLng(42.345573, -71.098326);
      var mapOptions = {
        center: fenway,
        zoom: 14
      };
      var map = new google.maps.Map(
          document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);
      var panoramaOptions = {
        position: fenway,
        pov: {
          heading: 34,
          pitch: 10
        }
      };
      var panorama = new google.maps.StreetViewPanorama(document.getElementById('pano'), panoramaOptions);
      map.setStreetView(panorama);
    }

</script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="panel-group" id="accordion">
<div class="panel panel-default">
<div class="panel-heading">
<h4 class="panel-title">
<a class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion"
href="#collapse1">Local Map</a></h4></div>
<div id="collapse1" class="panel-collapse collapse in">
<div class="panel-body">
**Google Map JS**
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="panel panel-default">
<div class="panel-heading">
<h4 class="panel-title">
<a class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" 
href="#collapse2">Street View</a></h4></div>
<div id="collapse2" class="panel-collapse collapse">
<div class="panel-body">
 <div id="map-canvas" style="width: 400px; height: 300px"></div>
<div id="pano" style="width: 400px; height: 300px;"></div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: @Mike E try the above answer.

Comment: Thanks for the reply - I have edited my original code above but it's not working. Does the JS need to be at the top of the page before the accordion is executed?

Comment: just copy the entire code and run it will work for you.and always use jquery min before bootstrap files because it needs jquery.